# Removing Left Recursion for S -> S(S)S | e

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction

It is in the Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools, Version 2. Section 2.4.6.

How to remove Left Recursion for S -> S(S)S | e

Thanks a lot!

Comment: please check the answer

Answer (score 1):

Left Recursive grammar:

```
   A -> Aα | β
```

Equivalent grammar without left recursion

```
   A -> βA'
   A' -> αA' | ε
```

For the given grammar

```
   S -> eS'
   S'-> (S)SS' | ε
```